# Ember way to implement a search dialog

Tags: ember.js

I want to implement simple ember app, where I have a search dialog, a list of results and a detailed view if I click on the results, something like this:

http://jsbin.com/tuyapabuhe/2/edit

The search method of the IndexController is doing an ajax request to populate the model, but I'm not sure if that is the best way to do it. I specially don't like the `var self = this;` part. Is there an ember way to do that search?

**EDIT**

I updated the example, now is doing an ajax request and is more realistic:

http://jsbin.com/wimogu/4/edit

Answer (score 1):

The ajax call should be happening inside the `model` hook for the `Index` route. Instead of `observes` you can just use a `property` as follows:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return data; // your ajax call here...
  }
});


App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  filtered: function() {

   var name = this.get('name') || '';
   var people = data.filter(function(el){
    if(el.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name)>-1)
      return el;
   });
   return people;
  }.property('name', 'model') 
});
```

Then, in your template you can just do

```
{{#each user in filtered}}
   {{#link-to 'person' user.id}}   
   <div>{{user.name}}</div>
   {{/link-to}}
  <hr/>
{{/each}}
```

Working solution [here](http://jsbin.com/narez/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: But I need the value of the property called `name` to do the ajax request. I don't get how the `model` hook can be notified with the new value. I updated my original gist to be more realistic: http://jsbin.com/wimogu/4/edit

Comment: You don't need to use the model hook, per se... If the query is going to be made based on controller properties, then just make the model a computed property and forget the model hook entirely.

Comment: @mpowered sorry, but I don't see how to implement that solution, could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment on another answer, I would suggest the following for AJAX calls based on one or more filters, complete with debouncing to limit the number of requests:

```
function handleSearch() {
  this.set('model', this.store.find('user', this.get('query')));
}

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  search: '',
  sort: 'first_name',
  direction: 'asc',
  query: function() {
    return {
      search: this.get('search'),
      sort: this.get('sort'),
      direction: this.get('direction')
    };
  }.property('search'),
  queryDidChange: function() {
    Ember.run.debounce(this, handleSearch, 200);
  }.observes('query').on('init'),

  actions: {
    clearSearch: function() {
      this.set('search', '');
    }
  }
});
```

I have this running in the wild right now and it works perfectly.

Comment: Also, delete the model hook for your route!